# Confused refreshing Angular custom directive / communicating between adjacent directives

Tags: angularjs

I am two weeks into Angular. I have watched several Pluralsight videos and read several post and this has resulted in great progress but also some confusion. I want to notify one directive of some change in another directive. Then refresh the directive. In other words, it needs to go back to the server with the selection from the first and pull the appropriate data.

I have read about eventing and things like $watch() but then I have seen others say to avoid watch and to use $emit and $on. I have even seen one article say to use transclusion.

I have access to Pluralsight and other resources. I will self educate if someone could just point me in the right direction.

My directive markup html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <dashboard-main-nav></dashboard-main-nav>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <dash-select ng-show="vm.isDashSelectionVisible">Selections</dash-select>
</div>
```

My app declaration: NOTE I know I need to get the param from scope but not sure how...

```
(function ()
 {
    "use-strict";
    ...snip controller setup etc..
    
    .directive("dashboardMainNav", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/Navigation/GetDashItems",
            scope: true
        }
    })
     .directive("dashSelect", function () {
         return {
             restrict: "E",
             templateUrl: "/Navigation/GetDashSelections/:" + $scope.??,
             scope: true
         }
     });
})();
```

routingController:

```
(function () {
    ...snip...
    function routingController($http, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        var isDashSelectionVisible = false;
        var dashSelectionId = 0;

        $scope.LetterSearch= function (dashSelId) {
            vm.isDashSelectionVisible = true;
            vm.dashSelectionId = dashSelId;
            alert("Letters Clicked: " + dashSelId);
        }
    }
})();
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<dashboard-main-nav>
    ....snip....
   <a href="#/ABCSearch" ng-click="LetterSearch(1)">Letters</a>
</dashboard-main-nav>

..... snip.....


<dash-select>
   <a href="#/NumSearch" ng-click="NumericSearch(2)">Numbers</a>
</dash-select>
```

I am not showing the $routeProvider config that wires up the routingController as that works fine. I just need to get that custom directive `<dash-select>` to grab the param from scope..refresh then update the dom.

Comment: It's hard to make `templateUrl` dependent on scope. It can be a function that returns the url but scope hasn't been created at that point and isn't available. What exactly would you need from scope and why is templateUrl dependent on it?

Comment: Well that was how I learned..perhaps incorrectly to hit an MVC action to load content into the custom directive. Perhaps what I need is for my click actions to make a call to the secondary mvc end point...get the data back onsuccess and then push that data object into the directive. I'm going to update the question with what I think is your question.

Comment: In days gone by yes, you might load server rendered html. Start thinking of back end as nothing but a data API and do what you are thinking...hit an endpoint for data and load a static html angular template. There are cases where it is practical to load different templates but again they are typically rendered by angular also